# grunt-castle : module dependencies are not installed

Tags: dependencies, gruntjs, castle

first of all, sorry for my English.
I have a problem when I add grunt-castle on my project, some dependencies of the grunt-castle are not installed, because these dependencies are including in the main package.json, so that does not install with grunt-castle.
My solution was add a section "scripts" in my package.json with a little script to force install dependencies.
Example package.json:

```
.....
"scripts": {
     "install": "cd node_modules/grunt-castle && npm install"
 }
...
```

This allows install all dependencies of grunt-castle after install the main modules of the project.

Somebody has a better solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, you mustn't do this ! It's not advice to do this. When you want to install a node module in your project, just use this command to install locally :

```
npm install grunt-castle
```

During the installation of grunt-castle, it will install node modules dependencies himself via package.json from grunt-castle.

Check before you want to install this node module, if you're not the node modules dependencies from grunt-castle, already installed. If this is it, you must uninstall the node modules dependencies.

Here's an example to show better what I want to explain :

- yourprojectname

  - node_modules

    - grunt-castle

      - node_modules
    - lodash
  - Gruntfile.js
  - package.json
  - ...

As you can see, node module lodash is already installed. As you know, grunt-castle have a dependencie with lodash. So, when you have installed grunt-castle, the node module lodash is not in the node module's list from grunt-castle. You must uninstall lodash and reinstall grunt-castle to have node module dependencies in grunt-castle's node modules.